# Universal certificate works for production but not development

Tags: ios, xcode, ssl, certificate

I generated a universal push certificate ("Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production)"), which works correctly on production (enterprise distribution).

However, when I use it with a development app (when I install it from Xcode) it doesn't work, and I get the error "The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized" (a PushSharp error).

My old development-only certificate does work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

My problem was pretty silly - I had a check in the code if the certificate is production or development. It returned 'production' because universal certificate matches the condition there.

Then it tried to treat it as a production app when it wasn't.

My second problem was that PushSharp requires the .p12 file to be exported only from the private key (select only the private key in the KeyChain and select "Export"), while Apple instruct to select both the certificate and the private key to export the .p12.

Answer (score 0):

When you take build from Xcode, it will treat the app as development build and will use only the development certificates for app and APNS.

If you want to test the production APNS certficate you need to take an Adhoc build.

Comment: "take build from Xcode" meaning install directly from Xcode?

Comment: The production works for me. I archive it as an enterprise distribution and I get the notifications.
The problem is when I install directly from Xcode..
It is not suppose to work? if so, what's the point of the universal certificate?

Comment: @RotemYakov "take build from Xcode" meaning install directly from Xcode? Yes. And to the best of my knowledge so far, there is no such a thing like universal APNS certificate in ios.